# probability/combinatorial question

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a 7 x 7 grid with each space consecutively numbered 1-49 (row one 1-7, row two 8-14 etc etc). How many ways are there of choosing any 6 numbers from 49 such that at most 2 numbers are chosen from any one column or row of the grid?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: Does the order you pick them in matter?

Comment: "such that no row or column includes 3 or more chosen elements" Is this equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Let S be the set of all possible choices of 6 numbers, let $A_i$ be the set of choices with at least 3 numbers from row i, and let $B_i$ be the set of choices with at least 3 numbers from column i, where $1\le i\le7$.

Using Inclusion-Exclusion to find the number of elements in $\overline{A_1}\cap\cdots \cap\overline{A_7}\cap\overline{B_1}\cap\cdots\cap\overline{B_7}$, we get

$|S|-\sum_{i}|A_{i}|-\sum_{i}|B_{i}|+\sum_{i<j}|A_{i}\cap A_{j}|+\sum_{i<j}|B_{i}\cap B_{j}|+\sum_{i,j}|A_{i}\cap B_{j}|=
\displaystyle\binom{49}{6}-2\binom{7}{1}\bigg[\binom{7}{3}\binom{42}{3}+\binom{7}{4}\binom{42}{2}+\binom{7}{5}\binom{42}{1}+\binom{{7}}{6}\bigg]+2\binom{7}{2}\binom{7}{3}\binom{7}{3}+\binom{7}{1}\binom{7}{1}\bigg[\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{36}{1}+2\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{2}\bigg]$

where the terms in the last set of brackets correspond to the cases in which the number in the
ith row and jth column is not chosen, where it is chosen and only 2 other elements are chosen from that row and column, and where it is chosen and 3 other elements are chosen from that row or column.

(Notice that all the triple intersections are empty.)

Comment: Aren't we counting some things twice, even with the $|A_i|$'s? E.g. cases where 4 choices are made in the $i$th row?

Comment: Yes, I am; I'll have to see if I can correct this.

Comment: I guess it would work if we denoted $3,4,5,6$ choices in each row differently, and most intersections would vanish, but that's quite hellish.

Comment: That's what I tried to do, so hopefully I got it right.  (Let me know if it still isn't right, though.)

Comment: Looks good to me, well done.